# Bootstrap star-rating shown 2 times recursive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, rating

As stated in [Bootstrap star-rating shown two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346698/bootstrap-star-rating-shown-two-times) I currently struggle with a similar problem.

```
<div class="row">
    <input id="input-id123" type="number" class="" min=0 max=6 data-stars=6 step=1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#input-id123").rating();
</script>
```

I used Bootstrap-star-rating v3.5.4 in combination with AngularJS Directive.

The generated code looks this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="star-rating rating-md rating-active">
      <div class="clear-rating clear-rating-active" title="Clear">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="rating-container rating-gly-star" data-content="">
        <div class="rating-stars" data-content="" style="width: 0%;">
        </div>
        <div  class="star-rating rating-md rating-active">
        <div class="clear-rating clear-rating-active" title="Clear"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i></div>
        <div class="rating-container rating-gly-star" data-content="">
          <div class="rating-stars" data-content="" style="width: 0%;"></div>
            <input id="input-id123" type="number" class="form-control hide" min="0" max="6" data-stars="6" step="1">
          </div>
          <div class="caption">
            <span class="label label-default"> Not Rated</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="label label-default">Not Rated</span
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- The `class = rating` directive does not affect the appearance
- without initialization it does not change to the rating style at all
- the id is unique

For the directive it is a simple html template looks like following

```
.directive('Rating', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            filterBy: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/scripts/partials/survey-rating.html',
    };
});
```

And in the view I use this markup

Comment: if you want directive work for a class then it should `restrict: 'C'`

Comment: the directive should work on a tag called `<rating ...>` and the rating of bootstrap is only part of what is generated in the  template, but even when breaking things down to this minimal example the occurred recursion remains

Answer (score 0):

As this directive was used solely in angular.js it was easier and more convenient to switch to angular-ui bootstrap in the directive

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/rating

In the directive I used the uib-rating which made the use of a controller unnecassary.

```
<uib-rating
    ng-model='rate'
    max='6'
    aria-labelledby='default-rating'
    ng-change='checkChange()'></uib-rating>
```